# How to disable future date in x-editable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins

I have tried so many ways but not success.
I want to disable future date selection from date picker in x-editable .
Here is my **html** code .

```
<a  href="#" editable-bsdate="TeamData.selectedDate"  
           onshow="openPicker()"
           onhide="closePicker()"
           e-is-open="TeamData.pickeropened"
           e-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy">

            {{ (TeamData.selectedDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy") || 'empty'}}  
</a>
```

Here is **js** code

```
var date = new Date();
date = $scope.TeamData.selectedDate.toLocaleDateString();


       //function for date picker when picker is open
        function openPicker() {
            $timeout(function () {
                $scope.TeamData.pickeropened = true;
            });
        }

        //function for date picker when picker is close
        function closePicker() {

            $scope.TeamData.pickeropened = false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got success
add **e-max-Date='TeamData.maxEndDate'** in **html** and set 
 **$scope.maxEndDate = new Date();** in **js file**

```
<a  href="#" editable-bsdate="TeamData.selectedDate"  
           onshow="openPicker()"
           onhide="closePicker()"
           e-is-open="TeamData.pickeropened"
           e-max-Date='TeamData.maxEndDate'
           e-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy">

            {{ (TeamData.selectedDate | date:"dd/MM/yyyy") || 'empty'}}   </a>
```