# How to limit number of symbols in Datepicker X-editable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, x-editable

I use an x-editable Datepicker. A demo is on this page: http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo.html?c=inline
It is possible to enter more than 4 numbers in year. How to limit this? Plugins are persona non grata.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Tried several variants, one of them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35980740/how-to-disable-future-date-in-x-editable/36057803 but didn't succeeded.

Comment: You should use a mask on the editable's input field...Therefore a third party plugin